# Why does my computer turn on when power is applied? And need to be restarted once before monitors will display?

Tags: multiple-monitors, power, desktop-computer, dell-precision, generator

Background: I have a tech van with a generator that outputs 120V 60Hz power into a circuit breaker panel that then leads into a 3000VA UPS. I have 3 Dell 3930 rack mounted computers with quadro graphics cards that connect to the UPS. They then use go to monitors via displayport cables.

Problem: When the generator is on and I plug in the UPS, all 3 computers immediately turn themselves on for 15 seconds or so, and then shut off. This isn't really a problem to me, but when I turn the computers on by myself for the first time, NO display gets outputted to any monitors. The computer seems to boot up normally. At this point I hardboot the computer by holding the power button for 5 seconds and then turn the computers back on and then display gets outputted to the monitors and everything is fine.

This is quite an annoying problem and I've pulled my hair out trying to fix this. Here is a list of things I've tried already to no avail:

- Made sure the van has a good connection to an Earth ground and that power is a clean 120V 60Hz AC. It's also run into a pretty good UPS (metered this out and from the UPS ground to earth I get 0.5 Ohms)
- Checked BIOS settings to see if there were any power settings that may be causing the issue
- Updated graphics drivers
- Tried different monitor cables
- Tried reinstalling windows
- Tried messing with power settings within windows
- Tried 8 different monitors (All monitors are the same brand though DELL P2418D)
- Hooked the computers up to a normal wall outlet inside my house and they come up the first time no issues

I have no idea what could be causing this issue, but it is 100% repeatable. Any help or troubleshooting ideas would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Is this a line interactive or online UPS (or a different type?) Other then your almost bare assertion about its quality we have no way of knowing if its the cause - and this seems likely. (  I'm not entirely sure how grounding defines the quality of the UPS - the switchover time is more relevant IMHO). Similarly, many smaller generators output horrible power when heavily loaded and UPS's often don't play well with them.

Answer (score 0):

Please help me understand the sequence of events. Is this the initial state?

- The generator is off.
- The UPS is unplugged from the generator, but operating.
- The 3 PC's are plugged into the UPS, and the PC's are off.
- The UPS is *providing AC power to each PC's and each peripheral* (whether individually, the device is on or off).

Then the following occurs:

- The generator is turned on.
- The UPS is plugged into the generator to recharge.
- **At that time,** the PC's cycle **on**.

If that is correct, then the most likely cause of the issue is that, when switching from battery operation to AC mains pass-through, *the UPS temporarily loses power for a few cycles*, or perhaps even creates a voltage spike.

**Remedies**

- [Set the operating system and/or BIOS of the PC's](https://www.wintips.org/setup-computer-to-auto-power-on-after-power-outage/) to **not** turn on when power is applied. This alone may be sufficient.
- Use a UPS that switches cleanly and more rapidly from battery to line, without a glitch. *N.B.* There are two types of UPS: [continuously online and interactive (switching)](https://download.schneider-electric.com/files?p_Doc_Ref=SPD_JSII-5YQSBR_EN). A *continuously operating supply* is *always* operating from battery, which is being charged when external power is available - such a supply should have *no* transient when plugged into the generator. However, it has lower efficiency and higher costs.
- Try using power-line filtering and conditioning to remove glitches.

  - A [power condtioner](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0002D017M) with RFI suppression might remove voltage spikes and noise.
  - A [voltage regulator](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00009RA60) might help if there *is* AC voltage, but it drops or rises.

Comment: This is the proper sequence of events:

The generator is off. The UPS is off (not on battery power). The 3 PC's are plugged into the UPS (Or a power strip, the UPS doesnt seem to be a factor). The PC's are off, no power is being applied. The generator gets turned on, and the breakers are open so power goes directly to the power strips that provide an outlet or the UPS. If I go directly to the power strip the computers then turn on. If I go into the UPS first, when I turn the output of the UPS to 'ON' then the computer instantly boot. After this the process I originally described occurs.

Comment: This process happens without fail and is repeatable. The third computer is actually plugged into a different UPS than the first two, and the same problem still occurs.

Comment: Still seems like the settings in BIOS need to be changed.

Comment: I've looked in the BIOS before and i couldn't find a single setting for startup on AC power applied or anything like it. Will try again though.